# How to find the derivative of $f(x)=\int_{-2020}^{x^{3}} \sin \left(\pi t^{2}\right) d t$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

By FTC, if the upper bound in the integral was simply $x$ then it would simply be $f'(x)=\sin \left(\pi t^{2}\right)$ right? But the upper bound is $x^3$, so how can I find the derivative?

Comment: Take $g(y)=\int_{-2020}^y\sin(\pi t^2)dt$ and then, as $f(x)=g(x^3)$, calculate the derivative of $f$ using the chain rule.

Comment: A better version of the FTC is
$$\mathrm{\partial}_x\left[\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(s)\mathrm{d}s\right]=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$f = g \circ h$$

where
$$g(x)=\int_{-2020}^{x} \sin \left(\pi t^{2}\right)dt \quad \text{and} \quad h(x)=x^3$$